# "Confirm Form Resubmission" problem. MVC servlets JSP javabeans

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, glassfish, javabeans

hey guys! why is it that everytime i click something on my website and try to go back one page, it says "Confirm Form Submission". Im running a local server. This is in contrast to other websites like facebook where i can go back a page without that annoying message asking me to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Explanation indeed :

> Because of the sloppy coding practices of web developers browsers were forced to add this message. the scenario is as follows:
>
> 1) user fills in form and submits (posts form)
>
> 2) the server process the post data and responds with a new page (confirm) marked as not cacheable
>
> 3) the user navigates to a new page.
>
> 4) the user  press back:
>
> for the the browser to display the page in step 2, because its marked no-cache, it must request it from the server, in other words do the repost of the data (do step 1). here is were the sloppy coding came in, if this was an credit card charge, and repost detection was not on the server, the card is charged twice. this was (is) so common a problem, that the browsers had to detect this and warn the users.
>
> the **best fix** is in step two, the server sends a redirect to the confirm page. then when the user accesses the confirm via history or back, its a get request, not a post request and will not show the warning.

source : http://forums.asp.net/p/1553589/3814773.aspx

Answer (score 0):

okay nevermind people. apparently i was using POST method everywhere. changing it to GET solves the problem. I think it has something to do with caching..